# cannot add fragment to fragmentManager

Tags: android, fragment

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager; 

Fragment fragmentHome, fragmentHome2;
FragmentManager fragmentManager;

private void setFragments() {
            fragmentHome = new HomeFragment();
            fragmentHome2 = new HomeFragment();
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_fragment_frame, fragmentHome).commit();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_fragment_frame, fragmentHome2).commit();
            Log.d(TAG, "added just ago: " + fragmentManager.getFragments().toString());
            Log.d(TAG, "added size: " + fragmentManager.getFragments().size()+"");
    }
```

But It's result: `D/MainActivity: added just ago: []`
`D/MainActivity: added size: 0`

Why?? Is that any problem with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with your code. At first, will result **empty**. But in another code,this will result the **no of fragments**. I use **BottomNavigationView**. You should write log in other code.

```
BottomNavigationView bottomnavigationview = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
bottomnavigationview.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(menuItem -> {
switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
   case R.id.navigation_home:
         // This will result all fragments and size.
         Log.d("Fragments ",fragmentManager.getFragments()+"" + fragmentManager.getFragments().size());
         return true;
........//your code
}
```

}